# How to get value from side menu with custom component based on drawer navigation

Tags: react-native

I faced with the following problem: there's my side navigation class:

```
import { createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';
import MapsScreen from '../screens/MapsScreen';
import DetailsScreen from '../components/DetailInfoScreen';


const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: MainTabNavigator
    },
    Maps: {
      screen: DetailsScreen
    }
  }, {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 120,
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

SideMenu.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Switch, View } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native-elements';


export default class SideMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      switchPosition: false,
    };
  }

  toggleSwitch = (value) => {
    this.setState({ switchPosition: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { switchPosition } = this.state;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 16 }}>
          {switchPosition
            ? <Text>Switch to Celsius</Text>
            : <Text>Switch to Kelvin</Text>
          }
          <Switch
            style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
            onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch}
            value={switchPosition}
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, there's a switch in my custom component. And so, can you explain me, how can I get the value of this switch from, for example, DetailInfoScreen? Or there are no ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect solution would be to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) . You can set value in any component and can get value in any component.

If you do not want to use Redux - Short solution would be Define a Global variable and you can get and set value in any component

**Create a Class DataHandler.js**

```
let switchStatus;

function setSwitchStatus(status) {
  switchStatus = status;
}

function getSwitchStatus() {
  return switchStatus;
}

export default {
  setSwitchStatus,
  getSwitchStatus
};
```

**Set Value in SideMenu**

```
import { setSwitchStatus } from './DataHandler';


toggleSwitch = (value) => {
    this.setState({ switchPosition: value });
     DataHandler. setSwitchStatus(value);
  };
```

**Get Value in DetailInfoScreen**

```
import { getSwitchStatus } from './DataHandler';

componentDidMount() {
const switchStatus = DataHandler.getSwitchStatus()
}
```